# PHP Replace subtag, inside string

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need to replace a virtual label, the customer can add a label for each virtual label

```
<?php
    $mycontent  = 'Test of text <<[with user-filled separator label: ]my_tag]>> and <<[Another delimiter ]my_tag2]>> and <<my_tag3>>';

    $replace_my_tag     = 'ab ab ab ab ab ab';
    $replace_my_tag2    = 'cd cd cd cd cd cd';
    $replace_my_tag3    = 'ef ef ef ef ef ef';

    //REPLACE MY TAG    
    //how to make this regular expression
    echo preg_replace('', '', $mycontent);

    //i want results (case exists $replace value)
    //Test of text with user-filled separator label: ab ab ab ab ab ab and <<[Another delimiter ]my_tag2]>> and <<my_tag3>>

    //REPLACE MY TAG 2  
    //how to make this regular expression
    echo preg_replace('', '', $mycontent);

    //i want results (case exists $replace value)
    //Test of text with user-filled separator label: ab ab ab ab ab ab and Another delimiter cd cd cd cd cd cd and <<my_tag3>>


    //REPLACE MY TAG 3  
    //how to make this regular expression
    echo preg_replace('', '', $mycontent);

    //i want results (case exists $replace value)
    //Test of text with user-filled separator label: ab ab ab ab ab ab and Another delimiter cd cd cd cd cd cd and ef ef ef ef ef ef end

?>
```

You need to create a regular expression that replaces labels easily
Regards
Marco

Comment: `preg_replace()` is to replace a `part` with a `part`, If you just want to check if `ab` exists in the `string` or not, Then use `strpos()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$mycontent  = 'Test of text <<[with label: ]my_tag]>> end.';
$replace    = 'ab ab ab ab ab ab';
 echo str_replace('my_tag', $replace,  $mycontent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% I understand the exact goal, so here is what I think might be the answer based on my interpretation of the question.

My understanding is that if the $replace variable exists you want to remove the angle brackets and square brackets, then replace 'my_tag' with the contents of $replace. I used a [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for this and just interpolated the $replace variable into a string.

But if there is no $replace variable, then I just use [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) as it's faster and the entire section is not needed in the content.

```
$mycontent  = 'Test of text <<[with label: ]my_tag]>> end.';
$replace    = 'ab ab ab ab ab ab';

if( isset( $replace)) {
    $mycontent = preg_replace( "#\<\<(.*?)\>\>#", "with label: $replace", $mycontent );
}
else {
    $mycontent = str_replace( " <<[with label: ]my_tag]>>", '', $mycontent );
}

echo "$mycontent\n";
```

If the case is that $replace will always exist, but the criteria whether or not it is empty, then I would replace the [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function with [!empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php). This will evaluate based on the content of $replace instead.

Comment: screen user

Name
Address
Number
City

<<cli_name>>
<<cli_address>>
<<cli_number>>
<<cli_city>>

is possible for my custumers increment separator

<<cli_name>>
<<cli_address>>
<<[, ]cli_number>>
<<[City: ]cli_city>>